# How to pass the XMLHttpRequest responseText in a Vue properties

Tags: ajax, vue.js, xmlhttprequest

I would like to be able to retrieve the response of my request and to be able to store it in a property, but I can't reach my property customerArray in the function onreafystatchange.

```
export default {
        name: "CustomerList",
        data() {
            return {
                customerArray: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            retrieveAllCustomer: function () {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url = "https://url";
                xhr.open("GET", url, false);
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                        if (this.status === 200) {
                            //Does not refer to customerArray
                            this.customerArray = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        } else {
                            console.log(this.status, this.statusText);
                        }
                    }
                };
                xhr.send();
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to point to customerArray inside onreadystatechange?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()` causes the `this` reference to change to the XMLHttpRequest object. Consequently, `this.customerArray` does not exist anymore. In order to circumvent that, create a new reference to the original `this`:

```
retrieveAllCustomer: function () {
    var comp = this;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "https://url";
            xhr.open("GET", url, false);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    if (this.status === 200) {
                        comp.customerArray = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    } else {
                        console.log(this.status, this.statusText);
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is due scope within the function, since it is not the same after onreadystatechange as before.

Use `() => { }` instead of `function () { }`:

```
...
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
     if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
...
```

[Here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26) you can read a good explanation about this.